# How can polymorphic mixin-like behavior be accomplished in Rust?

Tags: rust

*Forgive my "object oriented" mindset (for some value of "object oriented"), but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to create the following analogue in Rust:*

In Python, I can define a base class with a method as either abstract/unimplemented ( `raise NotImplementedException`) or with a default implementation.  Then I can create a mixin to override this base behavior.  Lastly, I can combine the base class and the mixin into one child class where the mixin method is the method that is bound to the child class.  I can do all this in service of trying to fulfill an interface requirement of another piece of code that interfaces with these objects.  I want to do this in Rust without using dynamic run-time polymorphism requiring the equivalent of C++ vtables. In Python I would do something like the following with the silly interface `do_it`:

```
def do_it(inst):
    inst.must_implement_me()

class Base:
    def must_implement_me(self):
        print('base default implementation')
        
class Mixin:
    def must_implement_me(self):
        print('mixin override new default')

class ChildClass(Mixin, Base):
    pass



do_it(Base())       # prints "base default implementation"
do_it(ChildClass()) # prints "mixin override new default"
```

When I try to achieve the same goal in Rust:

```
trait DoIt {
  fn must_implement_me(&self);
}

fn do_it<T: DoIt>(inst: T) {
  inst.must_implement_me();
}


trait Base {}

impl<T> DoIt for T where T: Base {
  fn must_implement_me(&self) {
    println!("base default implementation");
  }
}

trait Mixin {}
impl<T> DoIt for T where T: Mixin {
  fn must_implement_me(&self) {
    println!("mixin override new default");
  }
}

struct BaseClass();
impl Base for BaseClass{}


struct ChildClass();
impl Base for ChildClass {}
impl Mixin for BaseClass {}


fn main() {
  do_it(BaseClass());
  do_it(ChildClass());
}
```

`cargo run` complains:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `DoIt`:
  --> src/main.rs:20:1
   |
13 | impl<T> DoIt for T where T: Base {
   | -------------------------------- first implementation here
...
20 | impl<T> DoIt for T where T: Mixin + Base {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation
```

Is there a way to tell Rust that the Mixin implementation should win?  I understand there is ambiguity, but can I explicitly tell Rust which method implementation wins?  If not, how else could this be achieved?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, what you are ultimately trying to accomplish. Although it sounds like all you really want is to provide default method definitions for your trait.

Comment: @IInspectable, it isn't just a default method. It is multiple levels of default methods. I probably should have used the Animal example we all know and love where `Base` is `Animal`, `Mixin` is `Dog` ( or more likely  `HasLegs` for the idea of "mixin"), and `ChildClass` is `Dalmation`. `Dalmation` gets all the methods for `Dog` that override `Animal`, but doesn't have to actually implement the `Dog` methods.   Anyways, I get that I'm being super object-oriented in my thinking, but this pattern is fruitful in _some_ circumstances, so I need help from you all to translate the mental model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code above indeed is not possible in rust. Comparing to python there's no trait bounds order, therefore you cannot determine which implementation should be called (e.g. from `Base` or from `Mixin`). Your particular issue can be solved with default implementation for trait [[doc link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#default-implementations)] ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2af1564410c59306e8ccd0dd3a441fb6)):

```rust
trait DoIt {
    fn must_implement_me(&self) {
        println!("base default implementation");
    }
}

// ...

struct BaseClass();
impl Mixin for BaseClass {}

struct ChildClass();
impl DoIt for ChildClass {}
```

A little bit more complex static "overloadings" can be achieved soon (hopefully) with a nightly-feature ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6c5df5ea0744db3ab640ffe2c716afc0)):

```
#![feature(specialization)]

impl<T> DoIt for T {
    default fn must_implement_me(&self) {
        println!("base default implementation");
    }
}

// ...


struct BaseClass();
impl Mixin for BaseClass {}

struct ChildClass();
```

Nevertheless, even if you are fine with a nightly compiler, I'd rather suggest to avoid the last code example, since that feature is incomplete yet.

Comment: Ok, you've been helpful and your first sentence is telling.   Of course my example is just a toy.  In reality, I'm using a library's trait and thus (I believe)  I cannot override the base trait to provide the default implementation.  I'd love to see a generic base trait implementation and then throw-in or mix-in this other specialized trait to override my base trait's generic implemention.  Anyways, I'm sure I'm thinking wrong about the problem.

Comment: `impl<T: MySpecializeTrait> DoIt for T ...` that overrides a generic `impl<t> DoIt for T` would be super useful.  The base library I'm using already has the generic `impl<t> DoIt for T`, so I can't do my more constrained specialization of it.

Comment: That the *specialization* feature is dedicated for. Sorry, but I don't aware of any alternative there.

Comment: I really missed the meat of your answer.  `specialization` is _exactly_ what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Kitsu May I suggest add specialization and maybe a link to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to reuse a partial trait implementation. In Python you could use a class hierarchy or a mixin, with the difference that you can combine behavior with mixins.

Imagine we have a class generating a series of number in the interval 0-100 (bear with my convoluted example and pseudocode):

```py
class NumberGenerator:
    def generate_numbers(): ...

# We can reuse code with inheritance
class IntervalGenerator(NumberGenerator):
    def generate_numbers():
        return range(0, 100, self.interval)

class MultipleOf3Generator(IntervalGenerator): ...
class MultipleOf5Generator(IntervalGenerator): ...

# We can also combine mixins for greater flexibility
class IntervalMixin:
    def generate_numbers():
        return range(0, 100, self.interval)

class ContainsDigitMixin:
    def generate_numbers():
        return (n for n in super().generate_numbers() if self.digit in str(n))

class MultipleOf3Containing7Generator(
    ContainsDigitMixin,
    IntervalMixin,
    NumberGenerator,
): ...
```

The example in your question can be solved with inheritance, but you can't do real inheritance in Rust. The closest you can get is probably using another trait and using a generic with a default implementation:

```rust
trait NumberGenerator {
    fn generate_numbers(&self) -> Vec<usize>;
}

// We need another trait to emulate subclassing
trait IntervalGenerator {
    fn get_interval(&self) -> usize;
}

// This is where we make each implementation of our trait
// an implementation of the original trait
impl<T> NumberGenerator for T
    where T: IntervalGenerator
{
    fn generate_numbers(&self) -> Vec<usize> {
        (0..100).step_by(self.get_interval()).into()
    }
}

// We only need to implement the second trait
struct MultipleOf3Generator {};
impl IntervalGenerator for MultipleOf3Generator {
    fn get_interval(&self) -> usize { 3 }
}
```

In rust, this does not scale to mixins, because you would not need to implement every combination.

I think for Rust there are simple solutions, depending on what you are trying to achieve:

- Put the logic in a function and call that function in every implementation.
- Instead of a method, can you make a function that works on the trait object? You don't want to use dynamic dispatch, but is it worth making your code more complex for such a tiny performance benefit?
- You can also turn that on its head and use supertraits - if you have a fixed number of default parameter sets:

```rust
trait Student {
    fn university(&self) -> String { "Columbia University".to_string() }
}

trait Programmer {
    fn fav_language(&self) -> String { "Rust".to_string() }
}

trait CompSciStudent: Programmer + Student {
    fn hello(&self) -> String {
       format!(
           "I study at {} and my favorite language is {}",
           self.university(), self.fav_language()
       )
    }
}

struct Francesco {};
// Here, we can only override what we need, the rest is defined by default.
impl Student for Francesco {
    fn university(&self) -> String { "University of Rotterdam".to_string() }
}
impl Programmer for Francesco {}
impl CompSciStudent for Francesco {}
```