# Is it possible to provide default implementations of other traits through custom traits?

Tags: rust, traits, base-class, object-oriented-analysis

I have some questions from object oriented design. If I want to define a base class `Path`, which has two subclasses `File` and `Dir`, `Path` provides the `validate` method and the `from_str` method. For some reason `File` and `Dir` have the same implementation of `from_str` and different implementations of `validate`. How do I implement this?

That's my idea, but I don't have a way to give `File` and `Dir` a default implementation of `From<String>` via the `Path` trait:

```rust
trait Path: From<String> {
    fn validate(&self) -> anyhow::Result<()>;
}

struct File { /* members */ }
struct Dir { /* members */ }

impl From<String> for File { /* ... */ }
impl From<String> for Dir { /* ... */ }

impl Path for File { /* ... */ }
impl Path for Dir { /* ... */ }
```

---

I try `macro_rules` for reuse the codes, but I no not know whether it is the best way:

```rust
trait Path {
    fn validate(&self) -> anyhow::Result<()>;
}

struct File { /* members */ }
struct Dir { /* members */ }

macro_rules! impl_from_string{
    ( $( $ty:ty ),+ ) => {
        $(
            impl From<String> for $ty {
                /* ... */
            }
        )+
    };
}

impl_from_string!(Dir, File);

impl Path for File { /* ... */ }
impl Path for Dir { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Please do not try to make OOP "work" in Rust. You are going to have a BadTime™.

Comment: There are no classes and no inheritance in Rust. In object-oriented languages, X inherits Y means X _is a_ Y. But with traits in Rust, X implements Y means X _does_ Y. One way to rephrase your approach: let `File` and `Dir` both be structs that _do_ everything that a `Path` trait specifies

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do generic inheritance in Rust, but you can do a "default implementation" for a trait.  This effectively allows you to have a base implementation that may be overriden once, but every struct that implements that trait.  [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62579837/how-can-polymorphic-mixin-like-behavior-be-accomplished-in-rust)

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze I know that applying OOP design inside Rust is bad, but the problem is that when I start my project, I realize that I don't know anything about Rust design patterns. If I don't use OOP, I will have no idea about my project, is there anything that is an introduction to Rust design patterns?

Comment: @youthlicUlic My single piece of advice for someone starting with Rust and with only OOP experience would be to use composition. Then your code will have a familiar feel to it, but you will avoid _many_ OOP's pitfalls.

Comment: @youthlicUlic I would suggest taking a couple weeks reading [The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) from front to back. I mentioned traits as one possible approach, but you could also use a Rust enum, which is very easy to work with and has different tradeoffs: `struct DirPath {...} / struct FilePath { ... } / enum Path { Dir(DirPath), File(FilePatj) }` reads as "a `Path` is either a `Dir` or a `File`, with specific data associated for each case. I highly recommend learning lots about both traits and enums if you want to keep pursuing Rust